# Why is it that, given a rational function whose relata have equal degree, one may divide the highest exponent coefficients?

Tags: calculus, limits

I am aware of the following rule for evaluating the limits of rational functions:

If

[image],

where P(x) and Q(x) are two polynomials of equal degree, then the limit is obtained by dividing the coefficients of the terms with the largest exponent.

What is mathematical basis for this computational rule?

Answer (score 1):

Hint (assuming you meant the limit at $x \to \infty$):

$$
\frac{a_n x^n + a_{n-1} + \cdots + a_0}{b_m x^m + b_{m-1} x^{m-1} + \cdots + b_0} = \frac{x^n(a_n + \frac{1}{x}a_{n-1}+ \cdots + \frac{1}{x^n}a_0)}{x^m(b_m + \frac{1}{x} b_{m-1} + \cdots + \frac{1}{x^m}b_0)}
$$

Note that all terms $\frac{1}{x^k} \to 0$ as $x \to \infty$.